# Linux create columns from row

Tags: bash, awk, sed, row, multiple-columns

I have a text file with values, and I'm trying to create and fill a column from a specific row in the file. To be more precise, the input is the following:

```
<name>RELATIVE 1</name>
0.624790,-0.000000,0
0.493925,0.591035,0
0.363039,1.182079,0
<name>RELATIVE 2</name>
-24.621334,0.000000,0
-24.752199,0.591031,0
-24.883085,1.182072,0
<name>RELATIVE 3</name>
-49.868542,0.000000,0
-49.999397,0.591014,0
-50.130271,1.182033,0
```

and the expected output should be:

```
0.624790,-0.000000,0 <name>RELATIVE 1</name>
0.493925,0.591035,0 <name>RELATIVE 1</name>
0.363039,1.182079,0 <name>RELATIVE 1</name>
-24.621334,0.000000,0 <name>RELATIVE 2</name>
-24.752199,0.591031,0 <name>RELATIVE 2</name>
-24.883085,1.182072,0 <name>RELATIVE 2</name>
-49.868542,0.000000,0 <name>RELATIVE 3</name>
-49.999397,0.591014,0 <name>RELATIVE 3</name>
-50.130271,1.182033,0 <name>RELATIVE 3</name>
```

the solution could be in Bash, Awk or Sed.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '/^</{s=$0;next}{print $0,s}' file.txt
```

When a line begins with `<`, set the variable `s` to the contents of the line and skip to the next line. On other lines, print the contents of the line, followed by the contents of `s`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try `awk`

```
awk '/name/{s=$0}!/name/{print $0,s}' file
```

Comment: I like the fact that we even chose the same variable name :)

Comment: Your solution worked flawlessly as well. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '#n
 /<name>/ {h
   b
   }
 G
 s/\n/ /p' YourFile
```

add the latest *name* line to the current line using the holding buffer